# Date validation using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, datetime

can anyone please tell me how to check whether the entered date(24 hour format) in a textbox is valid or not using regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** use a regex to solve this. Use the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method.

```
DateTime dt;

bool bSuccess = DateTime.TryParse("2009-05-01 14:57:32", out dt);
if(bSuccess)
    Console.WriteLine("it's a date!");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of variations of regex that will work for validating a date.

The site [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) has some examples of regexes to start you off.

How you actually invoke the regular expression depends upon the environment you are using. In c# there is the regex class, in javascript you can use the RegExp() object.

What environment are you in?

Also, in most cases I think you would be better off using something other than a regex. For example, the `DateTime` struct in c# allows for date validation with its `.Parse()` and `.TryParse()` methods while Asp.Net has various validator classes, as does MVC.